# FutureBuilder update by timer

Tags: flutter

I don't quite understand how you can update future in FutureBuilder by timer.  I tried to create a timer and give it to the future, but it didn't work out and there was an error: type '_Timer' is not a subtype of the 'Future?'

my handler with a request:

```
Future<ObjectStateInfoModel> read(int id) async {
    TransportResponse response = await transport.request(
        'get',
        RequestConfig(path: path + '($id)'),
        TransportConfig(
          headers: {},
        ));

    ObjectStateInfoModel objectState = ObjectStateInfoModel.fromJson(response.data);

    return objectState;
  }
```

my FutureBuilder:

```
return FutureBuilder<ObjectStateInfoModel>(
        future: logexpertClient.objectsState.read(object.id),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            final data = snapshot.data!;
```

Comment: `FutureBuilder` is designed for one shot data, if you want to show multiple data snapshots use `StreamBuilder` instead

Comment: Have your `Timer`'s callback complete a [`Completer`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-async/Completer-class.html), and then you can give `FutureBuilder` [`completer.future`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-async/Completer/future.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on the advice of one of the commentators i converted FutureBuilder to StreamBuilder and created such a stream and then everything works correctly:

```
stream = Stream.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 5)).asyncMap((_) async {
        return logexpertClient.objectsState.read(object.id);
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use refreshable_widget, which is built specifically for this.

https://pub.dev/packages/refreshable_widget

```
   Flexible(
      child: RefreshableWidget<num>(
        initialValue: challenge.userParticipation!.donePercent,
        refreshCall: () async {
          final challenge =
               await cadoo.getChallengeDetail(
                   id: widget.challengeId,
               ); 
               return challenge.userParticipation!.donePercent;
        },
        builder: (context, value) {
          return DonePercentWidget(
            percent: value,
          );
        },
       ),
     ),
```

Pass a refresh call and how often you want to refresh, widget will build whatever on builder method.